# Regular expression that checks for existence at least 3 different characters in a string

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that makes sure that a string contains at least 3 different characters (of any type).

Example, aqaqaq is not valid because it is comprised of 2 different characters only. 
aqwaqa or aq3aqa or aq!aqa are valid.

Is that possible in regex?

Languages: Javascript / PHP

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, right. Javascript & PHP, but I believe it's the same for those two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regular expression containing negative lookaheads:

```
/(.).*(?!\1)(.).*(?!\1)(?!\2)(.)/
```

Examples:

```
> regex = /(.).*(?!\1)(.).*(?!\1)(?!\2)(.)/
> regex.exec('abab!aba')
["abab!ab", "a", "!", "b"]
> regex.exec('abababa')
null
```

Comment: Could you also explain it just a bit? Thanks

Comment: @Spiros: `\1` is a backreference that refers to the first `(.)`. The expression `(?!\1)(.)` means "any character apart from the character matched by the first `(.)`. Similarly for `\2`.

Comment: So, I could add .*(?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3)(.) etc at the end to add number of different characters I need

Comment: @Spiros: Yes, you could do that. `.*(?!\1|\2|\3)(.)` would also work and is slightly more consice (might be relevant if you're going to extend it further). You may also run into performance issues if you extend this further.